# Importing csv into Ruby on Rails application error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I am currently trying to be able to import a csv of Courses which consist of a course name and a professor. I'm having an error that I've been trying to fix with research, but I'm coming up blank.  I would appreciate it if someone could take a look and help me see what I am doing incorrectly.

in routes.rb

```
get 'import/index'
post 'import/index'

resources :courses do
  collection { post :import }
end
```

In course.rb:

```
def self.import(file)
    csv_text = File.read(file.path)
    csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, headers: true) 
    csv.each do |row|
        Course.create!(row.to_hash)
    end 
end
```

In courses_controller.rb

```
def import
  Course.import(params[:file])
  redirect_to course_path, notice: "Courses Imported!"
rescue 
  redirect_to 'index', notice: "Invalid file format"
end
```

In import index view:

```
<p>Import Course CSV:</p>
<%= form_tag import_courses_path, multipart: true do %>
  <%= file_field_tag :file %>
  <%= submit_tag "Import Courses" %>
<% end %>
```

my rake routes:

```
Controller#Action
        import_index GET    /import/index(.:format)                     import#index
                     POST   /import/index(.:format)                     import#index
      import_courses POST   /courses/import(.:format)                   courses#import
             courses GET    /courses(.:format)                          courses#index
                     POST   /courses(.:format)                          courses#create
          new_course GET    /courses/new(.:format)                      courses#new
         edit_course GET    /courses/:id/edit(.:format)                 courses#edit
              course GET    /courses/:id(.:format)                      courses#show
                     PATCH  /courses/:id(.:format)                      courses#update
                     PUT    /courses/:id(.:format)                      courses#update
                     DELETE /courses/:id(.:format)                      courses#destroy
```

I generated an import controller for the views. In retrospect, this was probably not the best way - I should have made a view in course instead. I am currently getting a No data received "err_empty_response" because it is redirecting to /courses/import, which doesn't have a view. I want it to route back to the courses page instead. I'm confused and feel like I might have convoluted the situation. If anyone can see why the csv import is not working correctly, please let me know! Thank you.

EDIT: 
Here is the error I'm getting from the log:

```
[2015-04-29 00:05:38] ERROR URI::InvalidURIError: the scheme http does not accept registry part: localhost:3000index (or bad hostname?)
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/generic.rb:1203:in `rescue in merge'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/generic.rb:1200:in `merge'

C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpresponse.rb:275:in `setup_header'

C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpresponse.rb:205:in `send_response'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:110:in `run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: Hi, can you show us the error-message and the first few lines of the stacktrace (the several lines of guff after the error) from your server logs? Also: is there an index action for your courses_controller? You say that you created an import_controller, but you are showing us a courses_controller? can you please be clear about what you actually have right now? :) Also: `course_path` -> that should be the path for a single, specific course - but you aren't passing it a course to show... should that be `courses_path` ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for getting back to me. Please see my edit for the error message. Yes, there is an index action, it just lists all the courses. I created an import_controller for the views, but am not using any actions, so I may remove it. Yes - updating the path to be courses_path fixed the error. Small things!! Thank you!

Comment: ok, I'll move that to the answers section then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`course_path` -> that should be the path for a single, specific course - but you aren't passing it a course to show... or that should be `courses_path`